# Кнопка, имитирующая нажатия клавиш клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, button

Поиск по содержимому страницы, аналогичный Ctrl+F в браузере. Влезть в его код нет возможности. Клавиша Enter отвечает за переход к следующему результату, сочетание клавиш Shift+Enter - к предыдущему.

Возможно ли создать кнопку на JS, при клике (мышкой) на которую будет выполняться имитация нажатия клавиши Enter (или Shift+Enter соответственно)?

Comment: Поиск браузера вы не включите имитацией нажатия кнопок.. Разве свой, кастомный поиск сделать

Answer (score 1):

Сложно ответить что-то конкретное, так как вы не предоставили практически никакой информации. Но имитацию нажатия клавиши можно сделать с помощью dispatchEvent. Если ваш "поиск" работает на ивент листенерах, то может сработать.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  console.log('keydown', event.key, event.ctrlKey);
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  console.log('keyup', event.key, event.ctrlKey);
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key: 'Enter',
    char: 13,
    ctrlKey: true
  }));

  document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
    key: 'Enter',
    char: 13,
    ctrlKey: false
  }));
});
```

```html
<button>Enter</button>
```